# Does JMeter's Connect Time(ms) statistic include time taken to upload file to server?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to determine if the JMeter statistic, *Connect Time(ms)*, from a **View Results in Table** listener includes the time taken to upload a file to the server.  The apache JMeter documentation does not specify.  Based on my own testing, it does appear file upload time is included, but I want to know for sure.

From my own testing, uploading the following files to a test server via an HTTP sampler had the following effect:

1. **No file uploaded:** Connect Time was half a second or less
2. **250mb file:** Connect Time was about 19 seconds
3. **500mb file:** Connect Time was about 39 seconds
4. **1gb file:** Connect Time was about 76 seconds

Comment: Your results certainly suggest that the files affect that stat. I was under the impression that it was supposed to be the time to establish a connection - so it *shouldn't* include the file upload time. I take it your overall time is about the same as the times you've noted (i.e. the 250mb file total time wasn't much more than 19 seconds)?

Comment: Steve, that was not the case.  The total **sample time** was 132800 milliseconds @250mb.

Comment: In that case, it is possible that the connection time is being affected by file uploads - but the actual upload takes place in that much longer time after the connection is established... so the question is; why would the connection time take longer in a file upload scenario (i.e. how does the file size affect connection times).

Comment: @slashzero Were you able to get a definitive answer on this?

Comment: @Barry: I was not able to get a definitive answer on this. The data seem to indicate file upload time is included in the connect time. This seems to be a bug in jmeter, so I filled a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect time should not take into account upload time.

If you see it does then first check your heap parameters and if issue is confirmed open a bugzilla bug.

**Edit 5 may 2015:**

You opened bug 57886 :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57886

Comment: Thanks! I did file a bug.